# затемнение спрайта игрока в Unity при входе в триггер-зону

Tags: unity3d, разработка-игр, шейдеры

Суть вопроса - нужно создать материал или шейдер, заставляющий спрайт игрока темнеть при входе в зону-триггер, а в идеале ещё и становиться обведенным красной линией, если у вас завалялось нечто подобное - буду рада, если скинете готовый код, если нет - то было бы неплохо и популярно объяснить, как такие вещи пишутся. Заранее спасибо!

Comment: Скажите какой у вас тип рендеринга URP или Стандартный?

Comment: так по дефолту насколько я знаю urp используется..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Можно сделать что-то вроде такого:

```
Shader "Custom/FightingmodeShader"
{
    Properties
    {
        _MainTex ("Texture", 2D) = "white" {}
        _Color ("Color", Color) = (1,1,1,1)
        _OutlineColor ("Outline Color", Color) = (1,0,0,1)
        _OutlineWidth ("Outline Width", Range(0.0, 0.1)) = 0.01
    }

    SubShader
    {
        Tags { "RenderType"="Opaque" }

        Pass
        {
            CGPROGRAM
            #pragma vertex vert
            #pragma fragment frag

            struct appdata
            {
                float4 vertex : POSITION;
                float2 uv : TEXCOORD0;
            };

            struct v2f
            {
                float2 uv : TEXCOORD0;
                float4 vertex : SV_POSITION;
            };

            sampler2D _MainTex;

            // Функция для преобразования вершин
            v2f vert (appdata v)
            {
                v2f o;
                o.vertex = UnityObjectToClipPos(v.vertex);
                o.uv = v.uv;
                return o;
            }

            // Функция для отображения пикселей
            fixed4 frag (v2f i) : SV_Target
            {
                // Получаем цвет текстуры
                fixed4 texColor = tex2D(_MainTex, i.uv);

                // Затемнение материала
                texColor.rgb *= _Color.rgb;

                // Создаем аутлайн
                float4 outline = tex2D(_MainTex, i.uv + float2(_OutlineWidth, 0));
                outline += tex2D(_MainTex, i.uv - float2(_OutlineWidth, 0));
                outline += tex2D(_MainTex, i.uv + float2(0, _OutlineWidth));
                outline += tex2D(_MainTex, i.uv - float2(0, _OutlineWidth));
                outline /= 4.0;
                outline.rgb = _OutlineColor.rgb;
                outline.a = 1.0;

                // Смешиваем цвет текстуры и обводки
                fixed4 finalColor = lerp(texColor, outline, outline.a);

                return finalColor;
            }
            ENDCG
        }
    }
    FallBack "Diffuse"
}
```

Comment: **Комментарии были [перемещены в чат](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/145206/discussion-on-answer-by-goldand-----unity----); пожалуйста, не продолжайте дискуссию здесь.** Прежде чем разместить комментарий ниже этого, пожалуйста, ознакомьтесь с [назначением комментариев](/help/privileges/comment). Комментарии, которые не запрашивают уточнения или не предлагают улучшения, скорее всего должны быть [ответами](/help/how-to-answer), размещены на [meta] или написаны в [chat]. Комментарии, продолжающие дискуссию, могут быть удалены.